# error installing package on a branch with install_github

Tags: github, installation, devtools

I've forked a package from github have made some changes. I'm trying to install the version of the package to which I've made changes with install_github(), but am getting an error message. Any suggestions?

The forked version: https://github.com/embruna/refnet

The edited version on the branch: https://github.com/embruna/refnet/tree/proposed-updates

I can install the forked version with:

```
install_github("embruna/refnet", subdir="pkg")
```

I tried to install the version on the branch with the following:

```
install_github("embruna/refnet@proposed-updates", subdir="pkg")
```

But then get this error:

```
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
    line 1 did not have 6 elements
ERROR: installing package indices failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/refnet’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: There were two problems: 1) the install_github syntax I used incorrect and 2) there was a folder in "pkg" that was throwing an error even after correcting the syntax. See below for details.

Comment: Using `ref` in the `install_github` call seems to solve this issue. Like so: `install_github("repourl",ref="branch")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that specifying the branch with `@` but the subdirectory with the `subdir` argument is confusing `devtools`.

This works for me (specifying both subdir and branch in the `repo` argument):

```
install_github("embruna/refnet/pkg@proposed-updates",
```

So does this (specifying both branch and subdir as separate arguments):

```
devtools::install_github("embruna/refnet",
           ref = "proposed-updates", subdir = "pkg")
```

The output starts this way ...

```
Using GitHub PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo embruna/refnet@proposed-updates
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/embruna/refnet/zipball/proposed-updates
Installing refnet
```

This is with devtools 1.12.0

Comment: Thanks Ben - both of those are failing for me and kicking back the error in the original question.  Also using devtools 1.12.0

Comment: The following works for me: `install_github("embruna/refnet/pkg", ref="proposed-updates")` But I have been seeing a lot of Server Errors (500) from the GitHub API recently, which may contribute to your issues.

Comment: I think there's a hierarchy here. `"embruna/refnet/pkg"` + `ref="proposed-updates"` works (because we specify the first three elements together and then add the ref), so does `"embruna/refnet/pkg@proposed-updates"`, and so would `subdir=..., ref=...` but `"embruna/refnet@proposed-updates"`, `subdir=...` goes out of order

Comment: Forrest is back! Hey Forrest...

I figured it out. I had created a folder with some sample datasets and included it in the "pkg" folder. Once I deleted it then I was able to install from the branch with no problems using Ben's options.

Comment: @BenBolker - my explanation + acceptance of you solution must have just missed each other.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install your `proposed-updates` branch with this:

```
install_github("embruna/refnet", branch = "proposed-updates", subdir = "pkg")
```

I get a bunch of warnings, but no error messages.

Comment: I tried and still no luck...it still installs the original. Both commands return the following as they start installing:

`Downloading GitHub repo embruna/refnet@master`


And looking at the code confirms it's installing the original forked version.  Thanks Kara, will keep at it.